# Passing indexed array in Swagger Editor UI

Tags: php, jquery-ui, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I have an API for sorting some items, I am using jquery UI sortable for sorting. When I pass order array to API, If I console, I get an array something like this in the below screenshot
[image]

So In swagger I am using like this:

```
 parameters:
        - name: video_order
          type: array
          items:
            type: string
          in: formData
```

It seems not working, see the Swagger window
[image]

What I am doing wrong here, How can I do it properly? any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like a bug in Swagger UI. I'd suggest creating an issue in the [Swagger UI repository](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues).

Comment: Possibly this bug: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/4146

Answer (score 0):

I have found this code works for me, If anyone come across this type of issue..

```
parameters:
    - in: body
      name: body
      required: false
      schema:
        $ref: '#/definitions/Model0'
      x-examples:
        application/json: |+
          {"video_order":[1215, 1151, 1202]}
```

for definitions:

```
definitions:
  Model0:
    properties:
      video_order:
        type: array
        items:
          type: integer
          format: int32
    example:
      video_order:
        - 0
        - 0
```

Comment: Just to clarify - the idea of this answer is to change the POST request type from form data (`multipart/form-data`) to JSON. It's acceptable if you control the receiving server - e.g. if you are its developer. But if you *must* use `multipart/form-data` and cannot use JSON, then the original problem is a bug in Swagger UI, which is being tracked in https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/4146.

Comment: @Helen Thanks for your feedback, surely that is a valid point, In my case I don't use a multipart/form-data, so I think this is ok.